# Removing missing LFS objects from git repository

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

I am missing a bunch of LFS objects in my git repository*, both on the clients and the server. I am aware that those objects are lost and that's okay. Unfortunately this means that `git lfs fetch --all` or even `git lfs push --all origin` will fail.

I would like to purge the "broken pointers" from the repository, either by replacing the binary with a dummy text file or by removing the pointer altogether. I am also aware that this involves rewriting history and that's also fine.

What would be the best way to proceed?

*To clarify, I am missing **some** LFS files on the server but not all of them and not for all revisions of those files.

For example, I have foo.png that has been modified in 3 commits:

- foo.png (Version 1, LFS Sha: 03cfd743)
- foo.png (Version 2, LFS Sha: 661f0797)
- foo.png (Version 3, LFS Sha: 5fa2f122)

The LFS server no longer has foo.png version 2, so I would like to remove that commit from history. Unfortunately git lfs does not tell me which commit is broken, it simply tells me that `661f0797` is missing.

(For the record, I have found the missing files so I no longer have this issue but the solution should still be interesting!)

Comment: I've tried using BFG to delete files with broken pointers (`java -jar ../bfg-1.13.0.jar -D "broken.file"`), while that works, it completely wipes the history of that particular file even though only one commit might be "broken".

I've also tried removing the specific commit with `git rebase -i brokencommit~1` and `drop`ing said commit, but then LFS complains that some files should have been pointers and `git lfs migrate import --everything --fixup` doesn't see this issue. In other words, it's a mess.

Answer (score 4):

This script worked for me - it removes all blobs that look like LFS files.

```
git filter-repo --force --blob-callback "
if blob.data.split(b'\n', 1)[0] == b'version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1':
  blob.skip()
"
```

Explanation:

- `git filter-repo` rewrites git history
- `--force` is needed to skip safety checks
- `if blob.data.split(b'\n', 1)[0] == b'version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1': blob.skip()`
  This script checks if the first line of the file contains an LFS signature and skips adding this file in such a case.

Comment: Can you please explain how this works?

Answer (score 3):

if you're still looking for a way to see what commit is affected, get the missing LFS object ID and use this command to find the commit:

```
git log --source --all -p  -S <LFS-OBJ-ID>
```

Comment: I have a similar issue but have no idea what to do with this information

Comment: the question was how to find the commit that introduced the breaking changes. What you do with this information is up to you. E.g. you could try to remove the commit or amend it..

Answer (score 0):

You can `untrack` files, the [manual is here](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-untrack.1.ronn).

### Examples:

Just a single file:

```
git lfs untrack "/path/to/my-file.gif"
```

With wildcard you can catch several files by one command:

```
git lfs untrack "*.gif"
```

Comment: The problem in this case is that I don't necessarily want to untrack those files (and knowing which files are broken is somewhat difficult since the errors are based on the SHA256s). `my-file.gif` might only be broken in commit 5, but fine in commit 1,2,3,4,6,7,8. Ideally I would only want to drop commit 5.

Comment: Mhm, that's changing the question somehow. About reading encrypted errors there is probably something to find here on SO, even perhaps not directly related to LFS.

Comment: question is if it's enough to provide empty or small dummy-files or if the files are still verified by file-hash.

Comment: I have tried to parse the output from git-lfs and simply replace the missing files by dummy files, unfortunately git-lfs verifies the files and the hashes do not match. For instance, if git-lfs complains that file '661f0797' is missing, I created a file in `.git/lfs/objects/66/1f/661f0797` but git-lfs sees that the hash of that file is not `661f0797`

Comment: Yes, I expected that. And possible that '661f0797' is not the full hash, so even if you create a file with that hash, it's still not right perhaps. But I remarked your edit, that you found the files ;-)

Comment: You had to find the mapping for files `foo.png (Version 2, LFS Sha: 661f0797)` to resolve the error-messages. But possible is that there is no mapping-table but the hashes are calculated on the fly.

Comment: Wait - 661f0797 could be in the data-table and you could look it up - no hidden datastore, just a simple table.

Comment: `661f0797` is indeed not a full hash because sha256 hashes are too long and would have added too much noise here :)

Answer (score -2):

Make git reindex and creat new entries to the files, please read the following

```
git reset [-q] [<tree-ish>] [--] <paths>...
       This form resets the index entries for all <paths> to their state at <tree-ish>. (It does not
       affect the working tree or the current branch.)

       This means that git reset <paths> is the opposite of git add <paths>.

       After running git reset <paths> to update the index entry, you can use git-checkout(1) to check
       the contents out of the index to the working tree. Alternatively, using git-checkout(1) and
       specifying a commit, you can copy the contents of a path out of a commit to the index and to the
       working tree in one go.
```

source : man git-reset

Comment: This is meaningless. How do you use this? What is the context? How do you reference an lfs hash? Does this hook into LFS?

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried a simple (**A backup is recommended before using the following command**) :

```
rm -f .git/index
git reset
```

Comment: What does that do exactly?

Comment: Please include details of what this does, why, and HOW it solves the problem.